# How to order Wagtail tags

Tags: tags, wagtail

I tried to create tags for my Posts as described in doc (tutorial My first website). But i need to show these tags in specific order. Is there some simple way or i just need to create own class with Orderable?

Comment: Just moving your comment up here to the question "[the tags are used] as simple way to present text subheadings and i need to keep these subheadings same for all posts". I do not fully understand what you are trying to do sorry - maybe update the question with a bit more detail of what you want the editing interface to be like. It sounds like you will need to do a related model and use InlinePanel to achieve the sub-headings concept but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed you have gotten to this point in the docs - [Tagging Posts](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/getting_started/tutorial.html#tagging-posts) and want to present the view of your `BlogPage` with the tags in a special order (eg. alphabetical). `Orderable` is if you want to do more complex admin interaction with `InlinePanel`s and ordering of related models, where you are asking the page editor to order related items themselves.

The tutorial has this code for your template `blog_page.html`:

```
{% if page.tags.all.count %}
    <div class="tags">
        <h3>Tags</h3>
        {% for tag in page.tags.all %}
            <a href="{% slugurl 'tags' %}?tag={{ tag }}"><button type="button">{{ tag }}</button></a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

To work with a custom ordering of your tags, you will need to set up a way to send your ordered tags to the template context. The easiest way to do this is to have a method added to your BlogPage model, we will call this `get_ordered_tags`.

```
    class BlogPage(Page):
        date = models.DateField("Post date")
        # other fields...

        def get_ordered_tags(self):
            """Specific ordered list of tags."""
            # ordered_tags = self.tags.order_by('?')  # order randomly
            ordered_tags = self.tags.order_by('name')  # order by tag name
            return ordered_tags
```

Further up the page you would have seen the docs on [Overriding Context](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/getting_started/tutorial.html#overriding-context), we will do something similar to add `ordered_tags` to our Page's context.

We can then easily make one minor change to our template, just replace:

```
{% for tag in page.tags.all %}
```

With:

```
{% for tag in page.get_ordered_tags %}
```

So instead of getting the tags in their default order, we are getting them in our specific order.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have no problem to order by name (for example directly in template), but in my case i need to specify order for each post.

I don't use tags as group of links, just as simple way how to present text subheadings and i need to keep these subheadings same for all posts. 

So, what i need is to specify, for each Post, which tag to use and in which order. Maybe it will be easier to create own Class to hold this info, but there is not so nice way how to show/edit this informations in Wagtail admin such tags have.